# Proving a Type is Uninhabited in Agda

Tags: agda, theorem-proving, induction

I've been learning Agda recently and I've been making a lot of progress but I'm stuck on one thing: proving that a type is NOT inhabited.

I have a relation on `Bool`s defined as follows:

```
data Test : Rel Bool 0ℓ where
    direct   : Test false true
    indirect : {j0 j1 j2 : Bool} → Test j0 j1 → Test j1 j2 → Test j0 j2
```

The `direct` constructor defined some of the relation, while the `indirect` constructor adds the transitive closure. Obviously in this example the transitive closure adds nothing, but in the actual problem I'm working on it's important.

I would like to prove `testNot : ¬ Test true false` but I can't work out how.

My feeling is that the type checker is smart enough to know that the `direct` constructor isn't useful, and in the `indirect` constructor `j0` is obviously `true` and `j2` is obviously `false`. This leaves only the two possible cases for `j1` to consider. The code I tried was:

```
testNot (indirect {true} {false} {false} () _)
testNot (indirect {true} {true}  {false} _ ())
```

I thought that the type checker would know that the only thing that can go in either of those absurd patterns is one of those two `indirect` constructors with the same arguments, leading to an infinite chain of constructors which is disallowed, hence the absurd patterns. This didn't work -- the error I get is

```
Test true false should be empty, but the following constructor
patterns are valid:
  indirect {._} {_} {._} _ _
when checking the clause left hand side
testNot (indirect {true} {false} {false} () _)
```

So I guess I need to prove this by induction on the depth of constructors: fist prove that `direct` does not have type `Test true false`, then prove that if no "shallower" constructors have this type then no "deeper" constructor can either and the theorem follows from induction. The problem is I don't know how to express this. What do you suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start by proving a positive statement about the value the
`Test` indices take:

```
open import Relation.Nullary
open import Data.Product
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality
open import Function.Base

test-indices : ∀ {i j} → Test i j → (i ≡ false × j ≡ true)
test-indices direct = refl , refl
test-indices (indirect p q) =
  let (_ , eq₁) = test-indices p in
  let (eq₂ , _) = test-indices q in
  let absurd = trans (sym eq₁) eq₂ in
  case absurd of λ where ()
```

Your result is then a direct corollary:

```
testNot : ¬ (Test true false)
testNot p = case proj₁ (test-indices p) of λ where ()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Is it generally the case that it's easier to prove positive statements by induction than negative statements, or does that just happen to be the case in this instance? And another question: did you use case_of_ as a way to get the lambda with the absurd pattern to type check? I can't tell what case_of_ is contributing to this.

Comment: It is indeed often easier to prove positive statements. As you can see in `test-indices`, I am reusing the positive evidence obtained by recursive calls to dismiss the `indirect p q` branch as impossible.
As for `case_of_`, the fact that it is *not* dependently typed gives enough of a hint to the compiler that it can make reconstruct the type of the function without an annotation. In type theory, it is in general impossible to infer the type of something like `(\ where ...) e` because the pattern-matching lambda could be dependent.